# svg viewbox unable to resize

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm unable to resize a svg to 20px to 20px. 
The below is the original code size of the svg which is huge 0 0 35.41 35.61:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
       <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>SVG</title>
      </head>
       <body>
       <h1>Testing SVG</h1>
          <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 35.41 35.61"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#000100;}</style></defs><title>B Tuerca BLACK</title><path class="cls-1" d="M362.88,771.63l-4.12-1.23a13.38,13.38,0,0,0-.81-2l2.12-3.93a1,1,0,0,0-.18-1.22l-2.5-2.5a1,1,0,0,0-1.22-.18l-3.78,2a13.39,13.39,0,0,0-2.46-1.05l-1.26-4.24a1,1,0,0,0-1-.74h-3.53a1,1,0,0,0-1,.74l-1.26,4.23a13.38,13.38,0,0,0-2.47,1.06l-3.78-2a1,1,0,0,0-1.22.18l-2.5,2.5a1,1,0,0,0-.18,1.22l2.12,3.93a13.36,13.36,0,0,0-.81,2l-4.12,1.23a1,1,0,0,0-.74,1v3.53a1,1,0,0,0,.74,1l4.12,1.23a13.36,13.36,0,0,0,.81,2l-2.12,3.92a1,1,0,0,0,.18,1.22l2.5,2.5a1,1,0,0,0,1.22.18l3.77-2a13.38,13.38,0,0,0,2.48,1.06l1.26,4.22a1,1,0,0,0,1,.74h3.53a1,1,0,0,0,1-.74l1.26-4.22a13.38,13.38,0,0,0,2.48-1.06l3.77,2a1,1,0,0,0,1.22-.18l2.5-2.5a1,1,0,0,0,.18-1.22l-2.12-3.92a13.36,13.36,0,0,0,.81-2l4.12-1.23a1,1,0,0,0,.74-1v-3.53A1,1,0,0,0,362.88,771.63Zm-17,11.19a8.43,8.43,0,1,1,8.43-8.43A8.44,8.44,0,0,1,345.91,782.81Z" transform="translate(-328.2 -756.57)"/></svg>

        </body>
      </html>
```

However, I then change the viewbox values to "0 0 20 20" without specifying a width and height to the svg itself and the size continues really big:

```html
<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>SVG</title>
         </head>
         <body>
           <h1>Testing SVG</h1>
           <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#000100;}</style></defs><title>B Tuerca BLACK</title><path class="cls-1" d="M362.88,771.63l-4.12-1.23a13.38,13.38,0,0,0-.81-2l2.12-3.93a1,1,0,0,0-.18-1.22l-2.5-2.5a1,1,0,0,0-1.22-.18l-3.78,2a13.39,13.39,0,0,0-2.46-1.05l-1.26-4.24a1,1,0,0,0-1-.74h-3.53a1,1,0,0,0-1,.74l-1.26,4.23a13.38,13.38,0,0,0-2.47,1.06l-3.78-2a1,1,0,0,0-1.22.18l-2.5,2.5a1,1,0,0,0-.18,1.22l2.12,3.93a13.36,13.36,0,0,0-.81,2l-4.12,1.23a1,1,0,0,0-.74,1v3.53a1,1,0,0,0,.74,1l4.12,1.23a13.36,13.36,0,0,0,.81,2l-2.12,3.92a1,1,0,0,0,.18,1.22l2.5,2.5a1,1,0,0,0,1.22.18l3.77-2a13.38,13.38,0,0,0,2.48,1.06l1.26,4.22a1,1,0,0,0,1,.74h3.53a1,1,0,0,0,1-.74l1.26-4.22a13.38,13.38,0,0,0,2.48-1.06l3.77,2a1,1,0,0,0,1.22-.18l2.5-2.5a1,1,0,0,0,.18-1.22l-2.12-3.92a13.36,13.36,0,0,0,.81-2l4.12-1.23a1,1,0,0,0,.74-1v-3.53A1,1,0,0,0,362.88,771.63Zm-17,11.19a8.43,8.43,0,1,1,8.43-8.43A8.44,8.44,0,0,1,345.91,782.81Z" transform="translate(-328.2 -756.57)"/></svg>

         </body>
         </html>
```

[image]

I then added a width 20 and height 20 to the main svg file and the results size is smaller however it's now cropped.

```html
<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>SVG</title>
         </head>
         <body>
           <h1>Testing SVG</h1>
           <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" height="20"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#000100;}</style></defs><title>B Tuerca BLACK</title><path class="cls-1" d="M362.88,771.63l-4.12-1.23a13.38,13.38,0,0,0-.81-2l2.12-3.93a1,1,0,0,0-.18-1.22l-2.5-2.5a1,1,0,0,0-1.22-.18l-3.78,2a13.39,13.39,0,0,0-2.46-1.05l-1.26-4.24a1,1,0,0,0-1-.74h-3.53a1,1,0,0,0-1,.74l-1.26,4.23a13.38,13.38,0,0,0-2.47,1.06l-3.78-2a1,1,0,0,0-1.22.18l-2.5,2.5a1,1,0,0,0-.18,1.22l2.12,3.93a13.36,13.36,0,0,0-.81,2l-4.12,1.23a1,1,0,0,0-.74,1v3.53a1,1,0,0,0,.74,1l4.12,1.23a13.36,13.36,0,0,0,.81,2l-2.12,3.92a1,1,0,0,0,.18,1.22l2.5,2.5a1,1,0,0,0,1.22.18l3.77-2a13.38,13.38,0,0,0,2.48,1.06l1.26,4.22a1,1,0,0,0,1,.74h3.53a1,1,0,0,0,1-.74l1.26-4.22a13.38,13.38,0,0,0,2.48-1.06l3.77,2a1,1,0,0,0,1.22-.18l2.5-2.5a1,1,0,0,0,.18-1.22l-2.12-3.92a13.36,13.36,0,0,0,.81-2l4.12-1.23a1,1,0,0,0,.74-1v-3.53A1,1,0,0,0,362.88,771.63Zm-17,11.19a8.43,8.43,0,1,1,8.43-8.43A8.44,8.44,0,0,1,345.91,782.81Z" transform="translate(-328.2 -756.57)"/></svg>

         </body>
         </html>
```

[image]

I read SVG documentation and I understood that if you do not specify the width/height, it will take the same user unit of the viewbox.
Is this issue related to the original size that the svg was exported into?

Comment: just add `width="20"` and `height="20"` before or after viewBox

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way your SVG is laid out, you don't need to adjust the `viewBox`. Simply setting the `width` and `height` at `20` will display it as desired:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>SVG</title>
  </head>
   <body>
   <h1>Testing SVG</h1>
      <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 35.41 35.61" width="20" height="20"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#000100;}</style></defs><title>B Tuerca BLACK</title><path class="cls-1" d="M362.88,771.63l-4.12-1.23a13.38,13.38,0,0,0-.81-2l2.12-3.93a1,1,0,0,0-.18-1.22l-2.5-2.5a1,1,0,0,0-1.22-.18l-3.78,2a13.39,13.39,0,0,0-2.46-1.05l-1.26-4.24a1,1,0,0,0-1-.74h-3.53a1,1,0,0,0-1,.74l-1.26,4.23a13.38,13.38,0,0,0-2.47,1.06l-3.78-2a1,1,0,0,0-1.22.18l-2.5,2.5a1,1,0,0,0-.18,1.22l2.12,3.93a13.36,13.36,0,0,0-.81,2l-4.12,1.23a1,1,0,0,0-.74,1v3.53a1,1,0,0,0,.74,1l4.12,1.23a13.36,13.36,0,0,0,.81,2l-2.12,3.92a1,1,0,0,0,.18,1.22l2.5,2.5a1,1,0,0,0,1.22.18l3.77-2a13.38,13.38,0,0,0,2.48,1.06l1.26,4.22a1,1,0,0,0,1,.74h3.53a1,1,0,0,0,1-.74l1.26-4.22a13.38,13.38,0,0,0,2.48-1.06l3.77,2a1,1,0,0,0,1.22-.18l2.5-2.5a1,1,0,0,0,.18-1.22l-2.12-3.92a13.36,13.36,0,0,0,.81-2l4.12-1.23a1,1,0,0,0,.74-1v-3.53A1,1,0,0,0,362.88,771.63Zm-17,11.19a8.43,8.43,0,1,1,8.43-8.43A8.44,8.44,0,0,1,345.91,782.81Z" transform="translate(-328.2 -756.57)"/></svg>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I see. Do you know why that could happen? I mean the way that the SVG file is laid out (?), since all I read online was to modify with the viewbox property. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

All the vectors inside `<svg></svg>` are set relatively to `viewbox` so changing it will only impact svg's workspace, not the vectors inside it.

To only scale the element just set `height` like other answer suggests. If the svg icon is supposed to scale with the text, like in a button, then use eg. `height="1em"`. This way changing `font-size` of the button will impact both text and the icon the same way.

If you need to change the `viewbox` anyway then here's the fastest way for that:

1. Edit svg file in text/code editor.
2. Set desired viewbox value.
3. Open the file in any svg editor eg. Inkscape or Adobe Ilustrator
4. Change the size of the object to fit new workspace and save.

You may want to use optimization during saving to get rid of all unnecesary properties or use other software to minify the file. For example open it in VSCode with [SVG](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jock.svg) extension enabled, right mouse button on the svg code and hit *Minify SVG*.